# Eclipse Debugger: Source not found for project references

Tags: eclipse

I am seeing a problem whereby the Eclipse Debugger cannot find the source for classes that are included as project references.
My application contains 2 types of referenced libraries: those in the Maven repository, and those that are included as part of a project reference to another project in my workspace.

The debugger has no issue showing source for any classes in the Maven repository.

However, when it tries to debug classes included using a project reference then it cannot find the source. Even when I click on the "Edit Source Lookup Path" and specify the location of the  project it cannot find the source. I have confirmed that the class in question does exist in the project's output folder so I'm not sure what the problem is here.

Can someone please help?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you need to add the projects that are "included as part of a project reference to another project in my workspace" as a direct reference to your project

Answer (score 1):

OK, I've resolved this almost as quick as I opened it.

The problem seems to have been caused by the way I was importing my application's project.

So in Eclipse, I imported this using m2e's File > Import > maven > Existing Maven Projects.

This resulted in dependencies that existed in my workspace being included as project references instead of actual jar file references to the Maven repository.

To get the actual jar file references to the Maven repository, I ran mvn eclipse:eclipse and my debugger was able to pick up the source code.

Is this a known problem with the m2e plugin?